# Detox hangs on Modal shown

Tags: react-native, jestjs, detox

I'm trying to run Detox test for my React Native application but the test won't execute whenever a Modal is shown.

I have a test script with a OTP modal. The modal is made using `react-native-raw-bottom-sheet`

Below is the content of the `OTP`

```
import RBSheet from 'react-native-raw-bottom-sheet';

return (
  <RBSheet>
      <View testID="otp_container">
        {...}
      </View>
  </RBSheet>
)
```

And I have a script then press the login button and display the OTP. But the script would be stuck

```
  it('should allow login with correct credentials', async () => {
    await element(by.id('login_button')).tap();
    await expect(element(by.id('otp_container'))).toBeVisible(); <-- Won't execute
  });
```

If a run the close OTP modal, the test would continue but the test would fail since the otp_container doesn't exist anymore. Please help

Comment: Did you try wrapping the RBSheet in a View and putting the testID on that?

Comment: That didn't work. I managed to fix it using other library